# Why do I get \section wrong in the pdf

Tags: miktex

I updated the Tex studio two days ago and after that I get the \section wrong. Instead of getting the section title I get ˽ section-title & [] notes

```
\section{Blóðbankinn (1)}
\label{Blodbankinn01}
$\Box$ (vantar)\\
```

this come out as: ˽Blóðbankinn (1) [] (vantar)
Should be: 
  Blóðbankinn

[] (vantar)

Best wishes
Tómas

Answer (score 0):

I found the error I had somehow put \newbox instead of \newpage at one place and that corrupted the output.

Kind regards
Tómas